# Restructure data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a schedule in Excel.

I have a list of names on the left, next to it is their schedules every 15 minutes starting 11AM (11AM column, 11:15AM, etc etc).

They will be given a task every 15 minutes like E (email), M (meeting), B (break).

I need to show in another table their schedules for each task. Like for example I'll have a column Email, and for each name the email column will show their schedules for Email task based on the first table with their scheduled task every minutes.

The email column should show 11AM-12PM (example).

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please upload sample data, Source & expected ?

Comment: I'd recommend You to create UDF performed this task.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x2Sn9By

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
Function MakeCompact(times As Range, shedules As Range, letter As String) As String
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
If times.Cells.Count <> shedules.Cells.Count + 1 Then
    MakeCompact = "Error. Wrong source data."
    Exit Function
End If
n = times.Cells.Count
MakeCompact = ""
For i = 1 To n
    If letter = shedules.Cells(1, i).Value Then
        If Right(MakeCompact, 1) <> "-" Then
            MakeCompact = MakeCompact & "," & times.Cells(1, i).Value & "-"
        End If
    Else
        If Right(MakeCompact, 1) = "-" Then
            MakeCompact = MakeCompact & times.Cells(1, i).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
MakeCompact = Mid(MakeCompact, 2)
End Function
```

Usage:

Create the table:

```
     A      B   C   D   E   F   G
1    name   1   2   3   4   5   6
2    bob    m   m   b   m   m   
3    fred   b   m       e   e   
4                           
5           m   b   e           
6    bob                
7    fred
```

The range A1:G7 is source data (row 1 is header).

The range A5:D7 is a table we want to fill.

Insert into B6 the formula:

```
=MakeCompact($B$1:$G$1;$B2:$F2;B$5)
```

Drag it horizontally and vertically to fill the cells.

I think this idea is enough to create Your task solution.

PS. Pay attention - there is an additional column over shedule time.

PPS. After debugging make the function Volatile.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Is this VBA?

Comment: Yes. It's VBA (macro in Excel terms).

Comment: Oh okay I'll try it out